# Serializing Foreign Key Field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=False)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Test(models.Model):
    PRIVACY_TYPES = (
        ('PR', 'Private'),
        ('PU', 'Public'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=False)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    privacy = models.CharField(choices=PRIVACY_TYPES, default='PR',max_length=15)
    testtime = models.IntegerField(default=30)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='',blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='',blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=True)
```

I am trying to serialize the test object to also include the username and id from the User model. Here is the serializer I am trying:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_set = QuestionSerializer(many=True)
    user = UserSerializer(source='user')

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'privacy', 'testtime', 'user', 'question_set')
        related_object = 'question'
```

The user serializer looks like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')
```

The question set serializes fine this way, but with the relationship the other way round, if that is the right way to describe it, for user then I get an empty object with this code. I have tried user_username and user.username in the fields, but that doesn't work.

I have searched online and looked at the Django-Rest-Framework documents, but can only find examples where the relationship is as the question to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope, I understand your question correctly.

## Your models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
        test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        text = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=False)
        number = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.text



class Test(models.Model):
        PRIVACY_TYPES = (
            ('PR', 'Private'),
            ('PU', 'Public'),
        )
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=False)
        datecreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        privacy = models.CharField(choices=PRIVACY_TYPES, default='PR',max_length=15)
        testtime = models.IntegerField(default=30)
```

My question is updated to show you what `ForeignKey` means. `ForeignKey` means `ManyToOne`. You have `ForeignKey` field in Question `Model` with reference to `Test` Model. Idea is, that you have Many `Question` and One `Test` (`ManyToOne`), and vice-versa One `Test` and Many `Question`.

## This is solution below.

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_set = QuestionSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'privacy', 'testtime', 'user', 'question_set')
        related_object = 'question'
```

And now use it,,,

```
test_obj = Test.objects.get(pk=1)
test_serializer = TestSerializer(instance=test_obj)
print(test_serializer.data)
```

Comment: Many thanks, that is exactly it! Can you let me know how I describe this relationship within the model as I get confused? Is it many-to-one?

Comment: Yes. ForeignKey is ManyToOne. I updated my answer and describe what it means. Good luck.