# Add related ForeignKey fields with serializer in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **Django REST Framework**

I have three models like

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Plan Name'), max_length=100)
    default = models.NullBooleanField(default=None, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), db_index=True)
    quotas = models.ManyToManyField('Quota', through='PlanQuota')

class Quota(models.Model):
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.CharFieldmax_length=100)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class PlanQuota(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey('Plan', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quota = models.ForeignKey('Quota', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have to get all `quota` and their value from `PlanQuota` in the plan serializer while getting a list of plans.

I have the following serializer

```
class PlanQuotaSerialier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlanQuota
        depth = 1
        fields = ['quota', 'value']


class PlanListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    plan_quota = PlanQuotaSerialier(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        depth = 1
        fields = ['name', 'default', 'created', 'plan_quota']
```

But there is no `plan_quota` in the response.

How can I add all Quota and their value for each plan in a single query (SQL JOIN)?

> Edit 2:

Adding `source` to the serializer field worked

```
plan_quota = PlanQuotaSerialier(source='planquota_set', many=True)
```

And the result is like

```
"results": [
        {
            "name": "Test Plan 1",
            "default": true,
            "plan_quotas": [
                {
                    "quota": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "order": 0,
                        "codename": "TEST",
                        "name": "Test Domain",
                        "unit": "count",
                        "description": "",
                        "is_boolean": false,
                        "url": ""
                    },
                    "value": 10
                },
             ]
       }
]
```

Can I club all fields from `quota` with `value` field in the `plan_quotas` list?

Comment: `plan = models.ForeignKey('Plan', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plan_quota')`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298645/serializing-foreign-key-field/56299879#56299879 - check this. I have already talk about this. Maybe this will be helpful for you.

Comment: I think your models are not properly aligned. Plan is directly linked to Quota as well as via planQuota ? Are these both different. If same then you can access Quotas from there itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PlanQuota(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey('Plan', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plan_quotas')
    quota = models.ForeignKey('Quota', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)

class PlanListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        depth = 1
        fields = ['name', 'default', 'created', 'plan_quotas']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it solved.

1. For the first query, added `source`

   plan_quota = PlanQuotaSerialier(source='planquota_set', many=True)
2. For removing `quota` key, added `to_presentation()` in the `PlanQuotaSerializer`

   ```
   def to_representation(self, instance):

       representation = super().to_representation(instance)
       if 'quota' in representation:
           representation['quota']['quota_id'] = representation['quota'].pop('id')
           representation.update(representation.pop('quota'))

       return representation
   ```